# Installing `setfacl` on Cent OS 6

Tags: permissions, yum, acl

My apologies if this is the wrong Stack Exchange for this sort of question — it seems like the most appropriate.

Which `yum` package should I install to get the `setfacl` command on my linux virtual server running Cent OS 6.  Or is `yum` not the way to do this?  Or does Cent OS 6 have a different way of setting up ACLs?  Or something else?

I'm a developer — I've setup a virtual server with a VPS hosting company.  They're imaged a virtual machine with Cent OS for me.  However, I don't have access to the `setfacl` command.  I need this command to correctly setup directory access for my Symfony log and caching folders (per [their instructions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup)).

My assumption is my VPS host set me up with a very bare installation and I need to have some security or access related package installed, but I can't seem to google up that package myself.  I plan on asking their support — but 1. We know how awful support can be sometimes, and 2. I'd like to know from the experts what the "right" way to do this is in case support is as awful as I think they'll be.

Any help is appreciated — (and don't worry, I only plan to use this VPS for IP restricted development)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find out what package provides the `setfacl` command:

```
sudo yum whatprovides "*/setfacl"
```

Here is what I get from running this command:

```
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
acl-2.2.49-5.el6.x86_64 : Access control list utilities
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-workstation-6
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/setfacl



acl-2.2.49-6.el6.x86_64 : Access control list utilities
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-workstation-6
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/setfacl



acl-2.2.49-4.el6.x86_64 : Access control list utilities
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-workstation-6
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/setfacl



acl-2.2.49-6.el6.x86_64 : Access control list utilities
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/setfacl
```

So, as you can see, if it weren't already installed, I would need to install the `acl` package in order to install the `setfacl` utility.

Answer (score 3):

The RHEL/CentOS way is with `yum`:

```
yum install acl
```

The file system on which you will apply ACLs needs to be mounted with the `acl` option in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: `acl` has been a default option for quite a while now.